# Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, laravel-vue

I am working on Laravel and vuejs project, previously vue template was working fine but after upgrading Webpack and related dependencies to v4, it's showing below error:

> [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: are you using vue-cli or ?

Comment: You need to provide some code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, finally found the issue. Inside the app.js file I previously defined the component as follows:

```javascript
Vue.component('component', require('./components/component.vue'));
```

but after upgrading webpack and related dependencies to v4, we need to require it with `.default` property.

```javascript
Vue.component('component', require('./components/component.vue').default);
```